# Handlebars: How to use an expression as an index for another expression?

Tags: handlebars.js

```
{{draft.packs.[draft.openpack]}}
```

The above doesn't display anything, while both draft.packs and draft.openpack exist.

Do I have to suck it up and write my own handlebars helper?

Comment: Yes, I think you have to suck it up and write your own (fairly simple) helper.

Comment: oh fiddle sticks. I'll leave this open for another day or two, but otherwise I'll answer it as such and mark it as answered.
Thanks anyways :)